# using self to get current object in model, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, self

i was wondering if it was possible to get the current object in a model? ie i have a

FavoriteRelationship model which

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :lesson
```

my lesson model is

```
has_many :favorite_relationships
has_many :users, :through => :favorite_relationships
```

i have an association with my user model as well (not important)

ive been trying to do the method inside my FavoriteRelationship

```
def lesson_owner
    self.lesson.user
end
```

to retrieve the user that belongs to that lesson in the FavoriteRelationship but it doesn't seem to work. it returns nothing, even when i do

```
self.lesson.inspect
```

retrieving even the lesson which is in the FavoriteRelationship model isn't working. could someone shed some light on how to do this?

i essentially want the lesson that's associated with the FavoriteRelationship model. in my FavoriteRelationship table, i have the attributes,

```
:id, :user_id, :lesson_id.
```

and the :lesson_id should be the value im trying to acquire so i can get the user afterwards

thank you for your help and time

@update.

so im basically using trying to grant a 'badge' when a user favorites someone elses lessons. i have..

```
def create
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:favorite_relationship][:lesson_id])
    puts 'before favorite'
    current_user.favorite!(@lesson) 
    puts 'after favorite'
    @favorite_relationship = @lesson.user    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @lesson }
      format.js
    end
end
```

my badge granting comes from...

```
    grant_on 'favorite_relationships#create', :badge => 'got-favorited',
         :to => :lesson_owner
```

which takes in a method that returns who im granting to, that's why i created that method.

when i do

```
puts self.lesson.inspect
```

nothing comes up, not nil or anything. i know that my favoriting works, it creates the relationship in the db. the only thing i could possibly think is happening is that...it tries to grant the badge before the relationship gets created. hmm...i put print statements and it does seem like it goes into lesson_owner after the create_favorite_relationship gets called and returns. maybe it hasn't created it yet in the db? like a millisecond too fast? the favoriting happens asynchronously.

do i need to have some more associations set up?

Comment: What's wrong with this the simple approach `@user = FavoriteRelationship.find(1).user`?

Comment: doesn't that just always returns the first row in the table?

Comment: That's just an example. Let's generalize it:`@fav_rel.user` or if you're trying to access it from a method of `FavoriteRelationship`, just call `user`. Or did I misunderstand your intentions?

Comment: oh ummm... i guess im trying to get the user from a method in the FavoriteRelationship model because i need the method to pass into another model(from a gem)

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What does it do?

Comment: it doesn't return anything. even when i do self.lesson.inspect, nothing shows up on my console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what does this `self.lesson.inspect` return? `nil` or `NoMethodError`? 
Show us your migrations and check what's actually in the database. 
This might be your relation is just missing the link to the lesson (`lesson_id` is NULL)...

Comment: Also, what do you do in the console to check `self.lesson.inspect`?
It's pretty strange you say it returns nothing. Looks like you just are not printing it out correctly.

Comment: You see no output, so that means lesson_owner method is not getting called, right? Is that grant_on thing working fine? 
One more point might be worth checking - try to reload self explicitly before inspection.

Comment: thanks for the help! i resolved it. i just resetting my db because the ids were all weird and didn't match correctly with my inputs